# Oracle - Deleting row from child table locks parent table

Tags: oracle, locking, foreign-keys, deadlock

We have deadlock issue in Oracle 11.2g. One potential reason why deadlock occurs is deleting from child table locks parent table. I searched from oracle documentations, and did't find any specification this kind of lock. Any explanation or reference of documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code.

```
CREATE TABLE table_parent (a NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE table_child (b NUMBER, a NUMBER,PRIMARY KEY (b), CONSTRAINT fk_relation FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES table_parent(a));

INSERT INTO table_parent VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO table_parent VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO table_child VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO table_child VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO table_child VALUES (3,1);
INSERT INTO table_child VALUES (4,1);

COMMIT;
```

Then delete 1 record from child table.

```
DELETE FROM table_child WHERE b=4;
```

When we look V$LOCK table before executing commit. There is two new lock that 'table_child' and 'table_parent' in type of 'TM'.

Here is the query to look V$LOCK table.

```
SELECT O.OWNER, O.OBJECT_ID, O.OBJECT_NAME, O.OBJECT_TYPE, L.TYPE
FROM DBA_OBJECTS O, V$LOCK L
WHERE O.OBJECT_ID = L.ID1;
```

**The question is why 'table_parent' has been locked?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For maintaining constraints that 'span multiple rows', which is the case for a foreign key, there are moments when one (ie. the DBMS) needs to serialize transactions. The moments at which serialization is required depend one-on-one on the type of changes that a transaction performs on the involved tables. Theoretically (in a DBMS that offers snapshot isolation, which is what Oracle does), only if the type of change is such that it could potentially violate the multi-row constraint, would the DBMS need to automatically serialize transactions (for instance by acquiring various types of locks).

Now in the case of a foreign key, one needs to ask oneself: when can a foreign key be violated? There are four scenarios.

- a parent row is deleted: will violate FK if child-rows still exist.
- a parent row's key is updated: will violate FK if child-rows till 'point to' old value of key.
- a child row is inserted: will violate FK if row points-to non-existent parent-row.
- a child row's fk-column value is updated: will violate FK if new column value points to non-existent parent-row.

All other types of transactions on the (2) tables involved can never violate the FK. So in your case, a child row is deleted, no serialization should be necessary. However Oracle probably has some 'implementation specific' reason, which forces it to do acquire some kind of lock.

I've seen a different scenario where Oracle performs this kind of "unnecessary" locking too: you can find it here https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10050753&#10050753

Toon

Comment: Thank you for reply. Your explanation seems very logically true. Does this kind of lock has name or term? –

By the way, There is very confusing note in official document in "Locks and Foreign Keys".
Note: _"DML on a child table does not acquire a table lock on the parent table."_
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/consist.htm#autoId24

Comment: The academic term for the locks required to assure correct constraint validation (and thus transaction serialization) is: predicate locks. However the concept of a predicate lock is not implemented by DBMS vendors. So instead they resort to locking data objects (tables and/or index entries).

Answer (score 2):

Add an index on the table_child(a) column -- you always index foreign key columns for just this reason.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this is explained with examples here http://www.oraclebin.com/2012/12/what-is-deadlock-in-oracle.html